# How do I set this HDMI output fix permanent?

Tags: ubuntu, boot, audio, nvidia, hdmi

I finally found out how to make my Pop!_OS  recognize my HDMI for audio. (basically I'm using an ASUS laptop with a 1060 hooked with a  monitor, everything was fine except for the HDMI audio output not displaying on the audio output list)

I followed [this guide](https://github.com/hhfeuer/nvhda#install) and it works flawlessly, but every time I reboot my machine I have to run this commands in order for the fix to apply again..

```
sudo modprobe nvhda
sudo tee /proc/acpi/nvhda <<<ON
```

I originally extracted the zip file on my downloads folder and followed the steps from there on, I'm aware I can now skip the make and install part and just just straight use the `sudo modprobe nvhda` to load the fix; I don't know if I can already delete that extracted folder (or should I move it to root folder/other..).

That's a separate question basically, but main question is how would I make a script that executes those 2 pieces of code on system start/boot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete the folder if you installed the module with `sudo make install`.

See https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=75985#c33:

> I can confirm that kernel module, posted by Maik Freudenberg [[Comment 27]](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=75985#c27), is working fine on my system. Thank you for the fix. The HDMI audio device now works as it should.
>
> The steps I did to enable HDMI audio device:
>
> 1. Download and extract the file nvhda.tar.xz.
> 2. Run commands in terminal:
>
>    ```
>    make
>    sudo make install
>    echo nvhda | sudo tee -a /etc/initramfs-tools/modules
>    echo "options nvhda load_state=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/nvhda.conf
>    sudo update-initramfs -u
>    ```
> 3. Reboot.
>
> With this fix, I did not notice any problems with power management or system stability. HDMI audio works at system startup, after resume from sleep, after plugging/unplugging HDMI cable.

No need to write an extra script.

Related: [Nvidia NVHDA Non-Detected Workaround and Suspend Fix for NVHDA](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2407304) (ubuntuforums)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm pretty sure that guy is using the same laptop model as me; this has solved my issue.